# How to use scriptAlias in apache2

Tags: php, apache2

I have apache2 installed.
and I have 3 directorioes with index.php, all have the same index.php but just directory doc2 has data.php

- -doc1----> index.php
- -doc2----> index.php and data.php //in this directory i have index.php whitch content require "dates.php"

  - index.php

    ```
    <?
    print "Hello";
    require 'data.php'; //when it works show Hello there ?>
    ```
  - data.php

    ```
    ?> print "hello there" ?>
    ```
- -doc3----> index.php

I'm looking for the way to call data.php from -doc3 to -doc1 index.php and -doc3 index.php
I heard something about ScriptAlias, but I'm begginer with apache2, Does anyone know how to use it?

Comment: Are all 3 "doc" directories document roots for different sites? What exactly does this mean: **"m looking for the way to call data.php from -doc3 to -doc1 index.php and -doc3 index.php"**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a path relative to the curently-running php file:

```
<?php

    require '../doc2/data.php';
```

Answer (score 1):

The Alias directive allows documents to be stored in the local filesystem other than under the DocumentRoot. URLs with a (%-decoded) path beginning with URL-path will be mapped to local files beginning with directory-path. The URL-path is case-sensitive, even on case-insensitive file systems.

```
Alias /image /ftp/pub/image
<Directory /ftp/pub/image>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```